# math range error for apply sigmoid activation function to implement neural network algorithm

Tags: python, math, artificial-intelligence, backpropagation

I use `exp()` function in math package under the python and I implement function in order to apply sigmoid function. Below is the source code:

```
import math

def transfer(self, actavation):
     return 1.0/(1.0 + exp(-actavation))
```

And I use this function with dataset to parameter in loop

```
dataset = [[2.7810836,2.550537003,0],
    [1.465489372,2.362125076,0],
    [3.396561688,4.400293529,0],
    [1.38807019,1.850220317,0],
    [3.06407232,3.005305973,0],
    [7.627531214,2.759262235,1],
    [5.332441248,2.088626775,1],
    [6.922596716,1.77106367,1],
    [8.675418651,-0.242068655,1],
    [7.673756466,3.508563011,1]]
```

```
I get an OverflowError:math range error
```

I know why this problem occures. because it has too many calculate processes.

But I have to get a result. what if use rounding down?

how can I solve this problem??

Comment: This might be occuring because you might be calling the function with a large negative value.

Comment: i edit my dataset to only int type but it's same. what is my mistake?

Comment: Applying normalization on your dataset might help you a bit.